# How can I stop one instance via cmd of a process when several are running?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scilab

I start a program from a scilab script via the command line, `start myprog.exe`.

After the start my scilab script needs to keep going.

Now I want to stop exactly this instance of the process via the command line too, *even if several instances of the same program are running*.

Is that possible?

I know how to query via batch files whether a process of this program is running and then stop it, but I don't know how to get the exact allocation.

Is there something like a process id?

I use this to check if the process is running:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq ccx.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo Program is running
if not errorlevel 1 echo Program is not running
```

Comment: What about `kill` or `taskkill`?

Comment: But how do i stop the exact instance if multiple instances are running? Or asked differently, how do i get the allocation to the the process while starting it?

Comment: Do you know the process id (PID)?

Comment: You would need the speciific process id (pid). One could think of several ways to find it: generate a file on system startup with the pid, find the pid using the port that the process listens to, search for the pid in the application's log file.

Comment: Is there an easy way to assign a specific pid on startup?

Comment: No, Windows is assigning PIDs; you have to find out the PDI of the process(es) to close on your own; one way is to filter for a certain window title (use `tasklist` with `/v`erbose output to view them)...

Comment: Okay thanks. So a simple way would be to get all the instances of myprog.exe before start and after start and filter for that PID i guess?

Comment: Yes, @slyce, this could be another option...

Answer (score 0):

Use the command tasklist to view all running tasks with their PID 
then 
Taskkill /PID 26356 /F
or 
Taskkill /IM myprog.exe /F

Comment: Is there an easy way to assign a specific PID on startup?

Comment: As my known you can’t select the PID because it is generated sequentially by the OS. but you find the PID for a specific process.